# Using PHAR from a Web URL

Tags: php, http, phar

I'm working on a PHP server control panel with PHAR and I'm trying to add a feature so that if the resource PHAR doesn't exist it will automatically use the one from the site where you downloaded the control panel.
How can I do this?

What I have now:
$res = new Phar("phar://Resources.phar");

What I need:
$res = new Phar("phar://http://bootpanel.net/file/Resources.phar");

Comment: You're mixing protocols in that resource creation. You don't need `phar://` if you're using `http://`

Comment: Didn't even realize that XD Thanks